# Custom order by - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

table1

```
id     col_id       col_val    sequence
1      272          19         1
1      273          20         1
1      273          44         2
1      274          21         1
2      271          65         1
2      272          55         1
2      273          88         1
2      275          22         3
2      275          23         1
2      275          25         2
2      274          26         3
2      274          27         1
2      274          28         2
```

I wrote a SQL query:

```
select * from table1 order by id, col_id, sequence;
```

But I would like the order to be in the following way:

```
id     col_id       col_val    sequence
1      272          19         1
1      273          20         1
1      274          21         1
1      273          44         2
2      271          65         1
2      272          55         1
2      273          88         1
2      274          27         1
2      275          23         1
2      274          28         2
2      275          25         2
2      274          26         3
2      275          22         3
```

How can I get the output as above?

Comment: `order by id, sequence, col_id` won't this work?

Comment: No, I need the order by col_id but with all sequence 1, then order by col_id and all sequence 2 and so on.

Comment: so my `order by` does the same. It first orders id, then sequence, then col_id. which gives your desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

marking my comment as an answer.

You're looking for

```
select * from table1 order by id, sequence, col_id
```

This gives your desired result. All `col_id`s sorted with `sequence` 1 which is within `id` 1. and so on.